# Problems with solving a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problems solving following differential equations
 $$y'_1 = 2y_1 - y'_2 + y_2\\
y''_2 = -y_1+y'_2$$

I set $u_1 = y_1, u_2 = y_2, u_3 = y'_1, u_4 = y'_2$ which led me to $u'_1= u_3, u'_2 = u_4$ and $u''_1 = u'_3, u''_2 = u'_4$.

Then I got $$u_3=2u_1-u_4+u_2\\u'_4=-u_1 + u_4, $$ solving for $u_4$ which yielded

$u_3=2u_1 -(u'_4+u_1)+u_2=u_1+u_2-u'_4$.

So, is that correct and how do I solve $$u_1+u_2-u_3-u'_4=0?$$

And is there a way solving this with linear algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've invented more variables than you need.

What you want to do is create new variables as to reduce all of the equations to first order equations. Since you have a second order derivative, you should create a new variable to reduce its equation's order. Say: $y_3=y_2'$. Then $y_3'=y_2''$.

Your equations then become:
$$y'_1 = 2y_1 - y_3 + y_2\\
y'_3 = -y_1+y_3 \\
$$
and of course, we just introduced the new equation: $y_2'=y_3$.

Therefore,
$$y_1' = 2y_1+y_2-y_3 \\
  y_2' = y_3 \\
  y_3' = -y_1+y_3$$

In matrix form this is:
$$\begin{bmatrix} y_1' \\ y_2' \\ y_3' \end{bmatrix} = 
  \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

The coefficient matrix is diagonalizable ([Wolfram alpha will do this for you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B2%2C%201%2C%20-1%5D%2C%5B0%2C%200%2C%201%5D%2C%5B-1%2C%200%2C%201%5D%5D)). If you compute the eigenvalues: $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ with corresponding eigenvalues ${\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2, {\bf v}_3$. Your general solution will be
$${\bf y} = C_1 {\bf v}_1e^{\lambda_1 t}+ C_2 {\bf v}_2e^{\lambda_2 t}+ C_3 {\bf v}_3e^{\lambda_3 t}$$

Of course, you can ignore the third row of the vector solution since it corresponds to our "made up" variable $y_3$. :)